# Error in unziping on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, zip

edit: When trying to download files from this address https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-mobile-user-demographics/data, using

`wget https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-mobile-user-
demographics/download/gender_age_test.csv.zip`

the file is not dowloaded correctly - instead of zip format
`file gender_age_test.csv.zip`
gives
`gender_age_test.csv.zip.3: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators`

what can i do to downlad it correcly from command line (i'm using EC2 ubuntu)

Comment: Did you check the the file is actually a zip file? Because I downloaded it and it got downloaded as a cvs file?

Comment: @error2007s yes, they are downloaded as zip files, e.g events.csv.zip. on  my own machine they work correctly, the archive is extracted and I can open the csv.

Comment: events.zip.csv or events.csv.zip?

Comment: events.csv.zip of course

Comment: Are you running the unzip command in the same directory where the zip file is right?

Comment: yes. it seems that the problem is because of the download using wget...

Answer (score 0):

I've eventualy used this guide to http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-run-gui-applications-xfce-on-an-amazon-aws-cloud-server-instance/ to setup  browser on EC2 and download the files through it